# Dalvik VM couldn't find multiple methods

Tags: android

I don't understand due to which changes my app shows many dalvikVM warning messages. Even though the app seems to be working fine, there could be some potential risk. **I've gone through several related questions but none helped. I didn't trim the monitor output anymore than this because I'm not sure what might be useful or not.**

```
I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.

I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=GOOGLE_POLICY


I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/InstantRun: BootstrapApplication created. Android package is com.example.akash.chatapplication, real application class is null.
V/InstantRun: Cannot find external resources, not patching them in
I/InstantRun: Resource override is null
V/InstantRun: Cannot find dex classes, not patching them in
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 957: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
I/InstantRun: Starting server socket listening for package com.example.akash.chatapplication on android.net.LocalSocketAddress@4224fb98
I/InstantRun: Started server for package com.example.akash.chatapplication
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 692: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x004b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.stopLockTask, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 299: Landroid/app/Activity;.stopLockTask ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00b9
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 271 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00f1
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0101
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onVisibleBehindCanceled, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 219: Landroid/app/Activity;.onVisibleBehindCanceled ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0111
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 223: Landroid/app/Activity;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0137
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 271 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x019a
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 225 (Landroid/media/session/MediaController;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01b2
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2425 (Landroid/widget/Toolbar;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01bc
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.releaseInstance, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 230: Landroid/app/Activity;.releaseInstance ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02dd
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onActivityReenter, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 146: Landroid/app/Activity;.onActivityReenter (ILandroid/content/Intent;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02f4
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 748: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0349
I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View; from Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4642: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0432
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getVoiceInteractor, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 125: Landroid/app/Activity;.getVoiceInteractor ()Landroid/app/VoiceInteractor;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0490
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 28 (Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x055b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startActionMode, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 274: Landroid/app/Activity;.startActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0596
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showAssist, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 269: Landroid/app/Activity;.showAssist (Landroid/os/Bundle;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x05d8
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.postponeEnterTransition, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 227: Landroid/app/Activity;.postponeEnterTransition ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x05e3
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 760: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0672
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 233: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0787
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 64 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x07a1
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 271 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x07e8
W/dalvikvm: DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity; -> Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut;
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreateView, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4418: Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut;.onCreateView (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x082c
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.setContentTransitionManager, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 238: Landroid/app/Activity;.setContentTransitionManager (Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0940
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onProvideReferrer, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 199: Landroid/app/Activity;.onProvideReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x097e
I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop (Z)V from Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4644: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop (Z)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x09ab
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 676: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x09f5
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showLockTaskEscapeMessage, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 272: Landroid/app/Activity;.showLockTaskEscapeMessage ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0a05
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentTransitionManager, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 100: Landroid/app/Activity;.getContentTransitionManager ()Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0a0b
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 64 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0ac7
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getReferrer, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 115: Landroid/app/Activity;.getReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0b3b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 770: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0bb8
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteractionRoot, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 138: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteractionRoot ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0be0
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 756: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0c68
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getMediaController, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 108: Landroid/app/Activity;.getMediaController ()Landroid/media/session/MediaController;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0cac
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getSearchEvent, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 118: Landroid/app/Activity;.getSearchEvent ()Landroid/view/SearchEvent;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d2b
I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V from Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4680: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d6b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteraction, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 137: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteraction ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ddb
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 234: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e40
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 267: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e55
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAndRemoveTask, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 90: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAndRemoveTask ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e92
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 672: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ee9
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 68 (Landroid/app/assist/AssistContent;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0f5b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 89: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0f7f
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentScene, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 99: Landroid/app/Activity;.getContentScene ()Landroid/transition/Scene;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0f85
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2297 (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x10d2
W/dalvikvm: DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity; -> Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb;
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4425: Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb;.onCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x10fd
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startLockTask, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 293: Landroid/app/Activity;.startLockTask ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x11b2
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 724: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x1225
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 271 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/akash/chatapplication/IPSetupActivity;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x1329
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 297: Landroid/app/Activity;.startPostponedEnterTransition ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x1356
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onEnterAnimationComplete, referenced from method com.example.akash.chatapplication.IPSetupActivity.access$super
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 172: Landroid/app/Activity;.onEnterAnimationComplete ()V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x140b
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20203: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20205: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20209: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1021: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1043: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ColorStateListUtils.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

          [ 04-26 04:39:40.178 30063:30063 E/         ]
          Device driver API match
          Device driver API version: 23
          User space API version: 23 


          [ 04-26 04:39:40.178 30063:30063 E/         ]
          mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Many things seem to be wrong about my app and I'm looking forward to invest time to fix these problems. Since these problems seem to be something related to dependencies, here is the code for what might be necessary to look into:

Module app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akash.chatapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/com.github.ozodrukh/CircularReveal/1.1.1/jars/classes.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the build.gradle for my project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Finally settings.gradle has this tiny line:
`include ':app', ':classes'`

Comment: This is related with using compileSdkVersion 23, but deploying it on a lower API version. This is according to google. (Im facing the same issue) what i can find it's why this is happening now, and how to work around it.

Comment: @Gatunox please update me if you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

In Module app's build.gradle:

add  this line at the top

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Error: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.