# My app is working fine on Smart Phones but it is shutting down without any error on Samsung Tablet. Same functionality is working fine on phone

Tags: android, tablet

My Question was that i was having issues when i used multiple layouts for same activity my app was crashing, it came out it was because i changed xml for one layout but forgot to do the same in other layouts.

When I press the edit button from edit profile, calls code, the app stops working and shows the above logcat without showing any errors.

Comment: Might be the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852948/dalvik-vm-couldnt-find-multiple-methods).

Comment: and that question is also without an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue at that time as it occured to me i changed some xml layout code in my layout for Mobile phone but not for the tablet layout, thats why i was getting this error.